# iOS - import objective-c library project into a SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, static-libraries

I have a library project built in objective-c.
The project isn't built, and I currently don't have a lib.a file (I know I can just build the project and get the lib.a file).

Now I created a whole new SwiftUI project, and in that new project, I want to import the objective-c lib project and use it.

is it possible to do so? how can I compile and build the objective-c project, and use it as a library in the new SwiftUI project?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The modern way is to use SPM

1. Create module from your's Objective-C sources
2. Add it to SwiftUI Project

Have no headache with project configuration-linking

Comment: How do I create a module from the objective-c source? do you please have an example for that?

Comment: @RemoterUser same as swift source, you will need only append `publicHeadersPath` value in target parameters